# How to append the values from a Future List of objects to a simple List of objects

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `TextFormField` and onTap I display a `showSearch`.
In that `showSearch` I have a list of Vehicles which are hardcoded with dummy data.
I want to change that and to get the Vehicles from DB but I don't know how to convert a `Future<List<Vehicle>>` into a `List<Vehicle>`.
This is how looks my code:

```
class DBHelper {
...
...
// Function used to get all Vehicles from the DB.
  Future<List<Vehicle>> getVehicles() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query(TABLE_VEHICLE, columns: [
      COLUMN_VEHICLE_ID,
      COLUMN_VEHICLE_REGISTRATION_NUMBER,
      COLUMN_VEHICLE_ODOMETER
    ]);
    List<Vehicle> vehicles = [];
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        vehicles.add(Vehicle.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    return vehicles;
  }
}
```

```
class SearchPlateNumber extends SearchDelegate<Vehicle> {
...
...
// Function with dummy data
  List<Vehicle> loadVehicles() {
    var vehicles = <Vehicle>[
      Vehicle(id: 1, regNumber: 'DE99ABC', odometer: 1234),
      Vehicle(id: 2, regNumber: 'AB22SDK', odometer: 1234),
      Vehicle(id: 3, regNumber: 'KS88ASD', odometer: 1234),
      Vehicle(id: 4, regNumber: 'NV37SSD', odometer: 1234),
      Vehicle(id: 5, regNumber: 'PT20KLK', odometer: 1234),
      Vehicle(id: 6, regNumber: 'TEST123', odometer: 1234),
      Vehicle(id: 7, regNumber: 'VT20QWE', odometer: 1234),
      Vehicle(id: 8, regNumber: 'JS23POP', odometer: 1234),
      Vehicle(id: 9, regNumber: 'XX12WWW', odometer: 1234),
      Vehicle(id: 10, regNumber: 'AB01RCA', odometer: 1234)
    ];

    return vehicles;
  }

  // Function to get the vehicles from DB
  List<Vehicle> loadVehiclesDB() {
    var dbHelper = DBHelper();
    Future<List<Vehicle>> vehiclesList = dbHelper.getVehicles();

    List<Vehicle> _listVehicles = List<Vehicle>();
    vehiclesList.then((value) {
      if (value != null) value.forEach((vehicle) => _listVehicles.add(vehicle));
    });
    print(_listVehicles.length); // here I get 0 every time and in DB I have values
    return _listVehicles == null ? [] : _listVehicles;
  }
}
```

When I use the second function I don't get any values in my list.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

Here is a small demo to reflect my issue:

[https://github.com/user/FlutterVehiclesList](https://github.com/florentin89/FlutterVehiclesList)

Thanks in advance for reading this !

Comment: I think you need to await: <List<Vehicle>> vehiclesList = await dbHelper.getVehicles()

Comment: if you have a `Future<Something>` use `FutureBuilder<Something>` to get `Something` inside `build()` method

Comment: Can I use FutureBuilder inside a SearchDelegate ?

Comment: sure: it is a `Widget` so you can return it from `buildSuggestions` / `buildResults`

Comment: @pskink Do you think you can take a look on my small Demo which I just added to see what is the issue ? I tried your suggestion but is still not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what file do you mean?

Comment: searchPlateNumber.dart is the file. There my function `loadVehiclesDB` is not loading the items in my List. But if I use on line 72 and 73 the function `loadVehicles` (with dummy data) instead of `loadVehiclesDB` then everything is working fine.

Comment: here https://github.com/florentin89/FlutterVehiclesList/blob/main/lib/controller/searchPlateNumber.dart there is no `FutureBuilder` - the code you have there has nothing to do with your question asked here?

Comment: And how more exactly should I implement the `FutureBuilder` in that Delegate ?

Comment: `buildSuggestions` should return a `Widget` so you can return your `FutureBuilder` driven by `Future<List<Vehicle>>`, thats all

Comment: Thank you ! Is working !

Comment: sure, your welcome